# SQL using MAX() in WHERE

Tags: sql, aggregation

I have 2 tables:

- CUSTOMERS (ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS);
- ORDERS (ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, DATE_ORDER DATE, ID_CUSTOMER, AMOUNT);

Here is the task: get the first and last names of the customers who bought the biggest amount of a product in one order.

The orders without customer should not be considered. Please sort by `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME`.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
FROM CUSTOMERS
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.ID_CUSTOMER
WHERE AMOUNT = (SELECT MAX(AMOUNT) FROM ORDERS)
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: My code outputs nothing, tell me pls what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You can delete the group by.

Comment: The homework problem statement suggests that product should be in the query somewhere.

Comment: "orders without customer should not be considered" - you don't do it when computing MAX().

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME,
    CUSTOMERS.LASTNAME  
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUSTOMERS.ID IN (
        SELECT ID_CUSTOMER 
        FROM ORDERS
        WHERE AMOUNT = (SELECT MAX(AMOUNT) FROM ORDERS)
        GROUP BY ID_CUSTOMER
    ) 
ORDER BY FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
```